# Eclipse - Target “unknown” in Android device chooserr

Tags: android

I am using Samsung GT-S6802. When I try to select it in the 'Android device chooser', Eclipse recognizes the phone but not the target. It says target "unknown". Because of this problem, I can't choose the phone as the Android device.

How can I get Eclipse to recognize the target?

Comment: simply don't give minus ratings, i have problem that's why i asked!!

Answer (score 0):

This error can have multiple reasons. Try restarting adb with this shell command:

```
adb kill-server && adb devices
```

This restarts the adb server and outputs a list of detected devices.

If the target is still known restart the debuggin on the device. If that still not help reboot the device.